# Unable to hide the title field of content type

Tags: content-type, list-definition

I have created a custom content type and applying to the list, I want the built in title column to be hidden from the all forms.

I searched over the internet I found some solution but I am able to hide the field only from display from but not from the New Item Entry form.

My content type's `.xml` file is:

```
<ContentType ID="0x0100ACC91648A0A84876BF86BFD3BE085DD9"
           Name="Sample"
           Group="Custom Content Type"
           Description="My Content Type"
           Inherits="FALSE"               
           Version="0">
<FieldRefs>      
  <FieldRef ID="{52C03593-2F90-48BE-81FE-41399D0AA02E}" Name="oiplbLink"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{2A4A6602-6CFA-46A7-8CED-721764FB44EA}" Name="oiplbUsers"/>
</FieldRefs>
```

My list schema file is:

```
<MetaData>
<ContentTypes>
  <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0100ACC91648A0A84876BF86BFD3BE085DD9">

  </ContentTypeRef>

</ContentTypes>
<Fields>

  <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="Title"  Required="FALSE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" MaxLength="255" Hidden="TRUE" />
</Fields>

<View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generic.png?rev=23" Url="AllItems.aspx">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>          
      <FieldRef ID="{52C03593-2F90-48BE-81FE-41399D0AA02E}" Name="oiplbLink"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{2A4A6602-6CFA-46A7-8CED-721764FB44EA}" Name="oiplbUsers"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View>
</Views>
<Forms>
  <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
</Forms>
</MetaData>
```

Title field is disappeared from the display form only but not when the new item is created..

What am I missing?

Comment: I tried all [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594004/sharepoint-2010-hide-title-field-in-custom-content-type) solutions but not working/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the attribute UseLegacyForm=”TRUE” .

For e.g.

```
<Forms>
  <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx"  UseLegacyForm="TRUE" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
</Forms>
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use RemoveFileRef in Element.Xml file in

```
<RemoveFileRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title"/>
```

[SOURCE](http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2011/06/hide-parent-field-in-child-content-type.html)

Comment: I tried the way you suggested but the "Title" field comes when I click on new item link.

Comment: Try removing Title field reference from List schema file and then see.

Comment: I removed the title field from `<viewfields>` and also from `<Fields>` but still not getting the field removed.